# What is basis of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-topology

I think it is just 1; but I am also under the impression that it is just any open interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

Furthermore, I am trying to figure out how a compact interval $X = [0,1]$ inherite standard orientation from $\mathbb{R}$, from Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*.

To my understanding, "inherit from $\mathbb{R}$" means a linear transformation between $X$ and the basis of $\mathbb{R}$ whose determinant is positive, right?

Thanks.

Comment: The word "basis" means different things in topology and linear algebra. It sounds like you've heard the linear algebra word and are now encountering it in topology, is this true?

Comment: Exactly!! @EricStucky. So the basis is just 1 under the sense of linear algebra, but an open interval in terms of topology?

Comment: A single open interval won't be enough, no. (If you take the open interval (0,1) as a base for your topology, (2,5) isn't open, but it should be.) You can take the set of all open intervals, though. Or you could take the set of all unions of two open intervals. Or you could take all open sets. There are many bases.

Comment: @Jellyfish: Someone mentioned in a deleted comment that you need to know what field you are thinking of the real numbers as a vector space over. This is quite important: over the reals, the reals have one element in every basis. But over the rationals, the reals have infinitely many elements in every basis!

Comment: @Jellyfish: I don't really know how to answer your second question, though. Can you put in the question, the context in which you came across the problem?

Comment: Interesting @EricStucky. So over the reals, there is only one element in each basis, namely, the open interval; over the rationals, there are many elements in each basis, namely, the rational numbers. However, for this question, there is no ambiguity that it is over reals, right?

Comment: The questions is from Guillemin and Pollack's _Differential Topology_, about the discussion on orientation on Page 99.

Comment: @Jellyfish: Sorry that there has been so much confusion. Let me be clear. My previous comments refer to linear algebraic bases. You seem to be looking for an answer with topological bases. A linear algebraic basis of R over R has one element (like 1). A linear algebraic basis of R over Q has infinitely many elements (as you can imagine). A topological basis must be at least countable. Linear algebraic bases do not contain intervals. Topological bases always require more than one set for non-empty spaces.

Comment: I got you, thanks @EricStucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the context of topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29), a **basis** is a collection of sets which, when closed under union, form the entire topology.

This is similar to the spirit of the [linear algebra concept of "basis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29), in that you turn elements in the basis into all possible elements by applying the usual operation. However, it is quite difference in practice because a linear algebraic basis consists of *elements* in a vector space whereas a topological basis consists of *subsets* of a topological space (they are elements of something, but that something is not the space itself but the *topology*).

Therefore, a basis for reals is the set of all open intervals. By taking unions of intervals it is possible to form any open set; this is what is required.

EDIT: You mentioned that "an open interval" is a basis, this is not quite correct. Because in general on a topological space you have no notion of "translation", or "scaling", you will need* to include *all* of the open intervals in the basis. [[You could imagine that a topological vector space might benefit from a combined notion of "basis" that had these concepts packaged into it, but I don't know if this has standard terminology]].

Also, as Billy mentioned in the comments, a topological basis need not be unique.

Bonus: (*) Actually, you don't need quite all of them :) In fact, there is a countable basis for $\mathbb{R}$; this is one of the many things that makes the reals so awesome! I'll let you think about what that might be...

Comment: It is not Cantor set right? Since it has one-to-one correspondence with reals - so they has the same cardinality =B

Comment: Thanks so much Eric! I think I am specifically looking for the so called "standard basis" of $\mathbb{R}$. While I am asking for what it is here, I do know that the so called "standard basis" of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. I hope this help clarify my question. (=

Answer (score 1):

A basis for the usual Topology on $\mathbb{R}$? If that is what you want, it is the collection of unions of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, sure, the whole topology is a basis of the topology, but usually we want a smaller basis. But it is not at all clear what sort of basis he is talking about, since he talks about $1$ as a potential basis...